# In Cloudbee, can you deploy a php application to another host server via FTP

Tags: php, jenkins, cloudbees

I am new to Jenkins.

Does someone know that can I get source code from bitbucket (php) and upload them to another host instead of deploy to Cloudbee itself?

When I create a build, the only host service I can select is Cloudbee Run@Cloud service. I want to know can I deploy my php application to another host service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From CloudBees you can also deploy through some plugins to other PaaS providers. If you want to deploy to other providers you will need to develop your own Jenkins plugin or maybe to use some of the Jenkins plugins available to upload your artifact to the provider you want through SFTP for example.